# Why Laravel-Excel reads first row as column name

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I need to read an `.xls` file and put it into an array. I'm using [laravel-excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import) package for reading excel files.

I have a Excel file like this :

[image]

I need to have an array like this :

```
[
 '9921234567' => 'First Text',
 '9929876544' => 'Second Text',
 '9927654321' => 'Third Text',
 '9928765432' => 'Fourth Text',

]
```

**What I have tried so far :**

```
 Excel::load('sample.xls', function($reader) {
     $reader->dd();
 });
```

**Problem:**

The problem is it reads the first row as column!

```
0 => RowCollection {#619
      #title: "Sheet1"
      #items: array:3 [
        0 => CellCollection {#623
          #title: null
          #items: array:2 [
            9921234567 => 9929876544.0
            "first_text" => "Second Text"
          ]
        }
        1 => CellCollection {#624
          #title: null
          #items: array:2 [
            9921234567 => 9927654321.0
            "first_text" => "Third Text"
          ]
        }
        2 => CellCollection {#625
          #title: null
          #items: array:2 [
            9921234567 => 9928765432.0
            "first_text" => "Fourth Text"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Look, I don't want to first row values count as column name!

Any helps would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You linked answer in documentation

> Table heading as attributes
> By default the first row of the excel file will be used as attributes.
>
> You can change the default inside the config excel::import.heading. Available options are: true|false|slugged|ascii|numeric|hashed|trans|original

I never used laravel but just set it to false and check what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/2.1/import/results.html) says:

> By default the first row of the Excel file will be used as attributes

So, I recommend to use `noHeading` function:

```
Excel::load('sample.xls', function($reader) {
     $reader->noHeading();
     $reader->dd();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop thru each row. After that you can create your custom array when you loop thru all columns

```
Excel::load('sample.xls', function($reader) {
    $reader->each(function($sheet) {
        // Loop through all rows
        $sheet->each(function($row) {
            // Loop through all columns
        });
    });
})
```

This is just basic code for excel import, you need to adjust it to your example.

Hope it helps

Comment: No no... same problem